# Prestashop template hook call

Tags: hook, prestashop

I want to call a hook from template like this:

```
{hook h='displayCustom' mod='customcontent'}
```

I created a new hook and added method to module like this:

```
  $this->registerHook('displayCustom');

  public function hookDisplayCustom($params) {

      return $this->display(__FILE__, 'customcontent.tpl');

  }
```

I see that module triggered but there is no output. How can i fix it?
Prestashop 1.6, customcontent.tpl contents simple text 'TEST'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If smbdy will get in trouble with this.
Possible solution is:
There is a trigger in admin panel that turns off all other modules except native.
The path is: Admin panel -> Configuration -> Performance -> Turn off all non-native modules. It has to be off.